# customize list view web part using custom xslt in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, development, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

Inside our SharePoint 2010 we do some list view modifications using XSLT, similar to the one described in this link @ https://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-customize-list-view-web-part-using-custom-xslt-in-sharepoint-2013/.

Now we want to migrate our SharePoint 2010 site to SharePoint Online, but inside SharePoint online can we still use the same approach if we use online classic experience? or using XSLT will not be available in SharePoint online  even if we use the online classic experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might work, but then, it might not. XSLT can be very simple or very complex. XSLT code can be throttled by SharePoint online.

A [Microsoft Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/web-parts/fails-displaying-web-part-including-xslt-code) shows some troubleshooting when this occurs.

In general, you may want to rely on this legacy solution as little as possible and switch to the **modern experience**, where you can create customise views with JSON formatting.